# CUDA version of package not importing?

Tags: python, terminal, pip, pytorch, torch

Firstly, I installed torch 1.1.0, and then I installed its' dependencies. So, I can import torch_scatter 1.2.0 however I get this error when importing torch_scatter.scatter_cuda:

```
 import torch_scatter.scatter_cuda
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch_scatter.scatter_cuda'
```

I have Cuda v10 installed and I have a GPU. All of the requirements for this code were installed together through pip in one go on my virtual environment.

Comment: https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_scatter/blob/ff285368e57861cbd8194a91eec97153ba5d47c7/setup.py#L13

Comment: This might be a case where `pip` doesn't correspond to the `python` executable, even if it's in a virtual environment. Do `pip list` and `python -m pip list` give the same output, and are the relevant packages visible in both lists?

Comment: @9769953 Yep, they look the same to me! Both including all the right packages too.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by phd - it looks like the setup.py file of pytorch_scatter checks for and uses an available cuda installation automatically.

Also in the version you are using as seen [here](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_scatter/blob/1.2.0/setup.py):

```
...
if CUDA_HOME is not None:
    ext_modules += [
                   CUDAExtension('torch_scatter.scatter_cuda',
                  ['cuda/scatter.cpp', 'cuda/scatter_kernel.cu'])
    ]
...
```

Might be a question of whether `CUDA_HOME` is available.

Installing from source might give you more information as suggested [here](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_scatter/issues/23).

Comment: Is it possible to check if CUDA_HOME is available anywhere? And do you know how do i install from source?

Comment: CUDA_HOME is imported as `from torch.utils.cpp_extension import CppExtension, CUDAExtension, CUDA_HOME`, so you could see if that works for you. To install from source, download the git repository into a folder, cd into it and use `python setup.py install`. The author of torch_scatter says that might result in errors not encountered when installing from PyPI.

Comment: Also, make sure you have checked CUDA is in your path as described here: https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_scatter/tree/1.2.0#installation